# Play on Linux, Steam Games

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

I have installed PoL and I have also installed Steam.  I want to use the Windows client rather than the Linux client because I doubt very much the games I have will be available on Linux client yet.

Anyway, I have heard that I should use different prefixes for EVERY game/application I install.  What's the best way to do this for Steam games?

Comment: You wind up installing steam loads of times or softlinking it around.

Comment: So what do you suggest as an alternative then?

Answer (score -2):

Well, not alot of games will run through playonlinux and then with Steam, the only Windows/Mac game that I've seen that ran on linux for play on linux and then steam is "haunted"  And the graphics were great with 760 GTX, everything looked really pretty.  Unfortunately haunted is a game like Myst which really isn't my thing.  But if you like Myst, download haunted through play on linux, and then steam.  If you purchase crossover, you can use that and run some more games that won't run otherwise.  One game you can run with crossover is Rift if you run crossover with steam, and you can play that at max graphics also flawlessly.  If you like free games, you should try World of Warcraft at the molten wow website.  Oddly enough World of Warcraft runs flawlessly with the newest wines, it's really pretty cool.  And it runs like it does in Windows, yay.  Unfortunately the GMs there are a tad unfair, I was permabanned from it after I had 3 accounts that were worth 70 million gold; even though I wasn't running any cheats or exploits bans are not appealable.  But, so far that has been the best gaming experience I've had in Linux, and WoW is a great game.  Just watch the number of auctions you're keeping reposted, and don't have a private guild bank because apparently that looks suspicious and they can get confused and ban you for it.